# Swift memory conflict where it should not happen

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI project, where I use the MVVM-architecture.

When changing a View-model object property from the SwiftUI view, it causes a memory conflict crash in the view-model object.

The error is of the type: *Simultaneous accesses to 0x600003591b48, but modification requires exclusive access.*

In steps, here is what happens:

1. View-model property is changed from view
2. View-model property changes model property
3. Model property notifies about changes
4. View-model receives change notification
5. View-model access model object
6. Crash occur due to memory conflict

Relevant code snippets are seen below. Xcode project is a standard SwiftUI project.

The error will happen, after first clicking the add button, and then the modify button.

If the "update" code is moved into the "receiveValue" closure, the error will not occur. Likewise, the error will not occur, if the View-model class is made non-generic.

To my best knowledge, the code is all-right, so I suspect it is a compiler problem. But I am not sure.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var item: ViewModel<Model> = ViewModel<Model>()

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button("Add", action: { item.add(model:Model()) })
            Button("Modify", action: { item.selected.toggle() })
        }
    }
}

protocol ModelType {
    
    var objectDidChange: ObservableObjectPublisher { get }
    
    var selected: Bool { get set }
}

class Model: ModelType {
    
    let objectDidChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
    
    var selected = false {
        didSet {
            objectDidChange.send()
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel<Model:ModelType>: ObservableObject {
    
    var selected = false {
        didSet {
            model.selected = selected
        }
    }
    
    func add(model: Model) {
        self.model = model
        cancellable = model.objectDidChange.sink(receiveValue: { _ in
            self.update()
        })
    }
    
    private var model: Model! = nil
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    func update() {
        
        // Crash log: Simultaneous accesses to 0x600003591b48, but modification requires exclusive access.
        
        print("update \(model.selected)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using the ObservableObject protocol (and @Published)?

Comment: Good question? I did. As part of simplification, I removed it, to see if it will change something regarding the error. It did not change anything, and I did not put the original code back.

Comment: Yeah; that's why I deleted the comments. I figured it out. I'm just writing it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: require `AnyObject` for `ModelType`.

Long version:

You're trying to read from `self.model` while you're in the middle of setting `self.model`. When you say "If the "update" code is moved into the "receiveValue" closure, the error will not occur," this isn't quite correct. I expect what you mean is you wrote this:

```
    cancellable = model.objectDidChange.sink(receiveValue: { _ in
        print("update \(model.selected)")
    })
```

And that worked, but that's completely different code. `model` in this case is the local variable, not the property `self.model`. You'll get the same crash if you write it this way:

```
    cancellable = model.objectDidChange.sink(receiveValue: { _ in
        print("update \(self.model.selected)")
    })
```

The path that gets you here is:

- ViewModel.selected.didSet
- WRITE to Model.selected <---
- Model.selected.didSet
- (observer-closure)
- ViewModel.update
- READ from ViewModel.model <---

This is a read and write to the same value, and that violates exclusive access. Note that the "value" in question is "the entire ViewModel value," not ViewModel.selected. You can show this by changing the `update` function to:

```
    print("update \(model!)")
```

You'll get the same crash.

So why does this work when you take out the generic? Because this particularly strict version of exclusivity only applies to value types (like structs). It doesn't apply to classes. So when this is concrete, Swift knows viewModel is a class, and that's ok. (The why behind this difference a bit complex, so I suggest reading the [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md) that explains it.)

When you make this generic, Swift has to be very cautious. It doesn't know that Model is a class, so it applies stricter rules. You can fix this by promising that it's a class:

```
protocol ModelType: AnyObject { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suspected this was the problem, and for a start, I did try to constraint the generic like this. I did it in the following way:

class ViewModel<Model:AnyObject & ModelType>: ObservableObject  

Unfortunately this did not have the same effect, as setting the contraint directly on the protocol.

Comment: I changed status back to unanswered, as I still have troubles finding a solution that works for me. Problem is that making the protocol inherit from AnyObject solves the problem only partly. If more inheritance is added, the problem remains. For instance, if the protocol is constructed like: `protocol ModelType: AnyObject, ProtocolA, ProtocolB`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the latter example (ModelType requiring AnyObject and two other protocols). You'll need to post code that demonstrates this. (I can reproduce the `Model: AnyObject & ModelType` crash, which I recommend you open a Swift bug for. That should work, even though I'm a bit suspicious of needing this many protocols and layers; you may have over-complicated your design. Even so, it should work.)

Comment: If the 'objectDidChange' publisher is put into ProtocolA, and the 'selected' boolean property, plus a new description() function is put into ProtocolB, crash will occur. However, I have noticed combinations where it won't crash. Finally, I can't avoid having a lot of protocols in my original project, therefore, I am now using a hack that prevents view-model properties to cause callbacks into view-model model object. I see all this as a bug that should be reported and hopefully solved some day (in my original project the constraining protocol inherits from 7-9 minor protocols).

Comment: Changed my mind again. The original post do not constrain the generic to be a class, therefore the answer is all right. In addition, I will report problem as a bug in Swift.